# Preposition with substitute

Tags: prepositions, exam-questions

Is the preposition used with **substitute** same / fixed  in all sentences or it changes with meaning ? I tried to find my answer from google and found sentences mostly using *for* with substitute, on oxford dictionary website its mentioned that verb substitute is  *traditionally* followed  by *for*
so are there any exceptions to this rule ?
I have confusion between **to** and **for** in the following sentence.

> It is not a substitute ____ the formal criminal justice system, but a good backup to reduce its workload .

What should come in the blank ? Substitute for or substitute to ?

Comment: **Substitute for** is correct

Comment: @SovereignSun Is  it  FOR just here or  always ?  can we  use TO also ( depending on sentence ) ?

Comment: [*as a substitute **to** (some "original")*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+a+substitute+to%2Cas+a+substitute+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20a%20substitute%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20a%20substitute%20for%3B%2Cc0) is relatively rare, but not unknown. By including *traditionally*, your dictionary source quite correctly avoids explicitly claiming that ***for*** is the ONLY preposition that can validly follow ***substitute***. But for learners, that's probably all they need to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"...substitute *for* the criminal justice system..." is correct in your example. You always substitute something *for* something else.

I can think of a situation in which you'd use "to" after "substitute":

> I used a substitute to avoid going to the grocery store.

However, in that example you're just not saying the part where you've substituted something *for* something else, shortening the sentence. The "to" phrase isn't telling us what was substituted; it's just telling us *why* something was substituted. We can include it with the other part:

> I used a substitute for the buttermilk to avoid going to the grocery store.

or

> I used a substitute for the buttermilk in order to avoid going to the grocery store.

The "to" has nothing to do with "substitute", which pretty much always takes "for".

Comment: "Substitute" is also a noun (as in your first example).  When used as a verb, I can't think of any preposition that follows substitute other than "for".

Comment: @Andrew True, that distinction hadn't even occurred to me. I could rewrite the buttermilk sentences using "substitute" as a verb and I think the point would stand. "I substituted to avoid going to the grocery store." A little clunky but technically correct, I think.

Comment: I'm not certain if "substitute" can be used as an intransitive verb without some object at least *implied*.  I think in your example the "to" is technically part of the adverbial phrase -- as you say, it has nothing to do with "substitute".

Answer (score 6):

The word *substitute* can take both *for* and *with*, but the preposition changes the meaning. It does not generally take the preposition *to*.

> Substitute X *for* Y
>   or
>   X *is a* substitute *for* Y

both mean that X (the first term) is replacing Y (the second term).

However,

> Substitute X *with Y*
>   or
>   X *is* substituted *with* Y

both mean that Y (the second term) is replacing X (the first term).

In your example, *for* is the appropriate preposition:

> It is not a substitute **for** the formal criminal justice system, but a good backup to reduce its workload.

because you want to say that "It" (the first term) is [not] replacing "the formal criminal justice system" (the second term).

If you wanted to rephrase using *with*, you could say

> The formal criminal justice system cannot be substituted **with** [the other system], but it is a good backup to reduce the justice system's workload.

Note that this distinction is subtle enough to trip up native speakers; it is safest to always use *for*, and make sure that the first term is meant to be replacing the second term.

Answer (score 3):

It's generally a good idea to memorize English verb/preposition pairs rather than just verbs or just prepositions, since many verbs can change meaning with a different preposition.  Consider "get on", "get over", "get back", "get up", and many others.

Usually you can find in the dictionary what prepositions go with each verb. [This one](http://www.englishpage.com/prepositions/verb_preposition.html) is not complete, but might be a good place to start.

The preposition to pair with "substitute" (the verb) is "for".  So, "substitute **for** the formal criminal justice system," is correct.

(Edit) "Substitute" can also take "with" as a preposition, which reverses the order of what is being substituted.

Comment: +1 for the idea that sometimes applying grammar rules just makes things more confusing, and the best thing to do is get out the ol' flashcards. :)